# Angular bootstrap injector error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap, angularjs-injector

I'm getting an injector error when I try to use angular bootstrap.
Here is the error:

```
angular.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=ui.bootstrapProvider%20%3C-%20ui.bootstrap%20%3C-%20AdminController
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:43:7
at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:40:270)
at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:43:69
at d (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:40:270)
at e (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:41:1)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:41:364)
at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:88:341
at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23742 <div class="template ng-scope" ui-view="">
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="FriendZone">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"       href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-csp.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="template" ui-view></div>

<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js">    </script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<script src="front/app.js"></script>
<script src="front/navigation/navigation-controller.js"></script>
<script src="front/landing/landing-controller.js"></script>
<script src="front/search/search-controller.js"></script>
<script src="front/profile/profile-controller.js"></script>
<script src="front/admin/admin-controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my admin controller:

```
    (function () {
angular.module('FriendZone').controller('AdminController', ['$scope', '$state', '$http', 'ui.bootstrap',
    function ($scope, $state, $http, $view) {
        $scope.getUsers = function() {

        };

        $scope.getUsers();
    }]);
```

I'm still quite new to Angular so it might be something really simple. Thank you in advance!

Edit: Routing code (app.js):

```
    angular.module('FriendZone', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/landing');
        console.log("hello");
        $stateProvider.state('landing', {
            url: '/landing',
            templateUrl: 'front/landing/landing.html',
            controller: 'LandingController'
        }).state('search', {
            url: '/search',
            templateUrl: 'front/search/search.html',
            controller: 'SearchController'
        }).state('profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: 'front/profile/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController'
        }).state('admin', {
            url: '/admin',
            templateUrl: 'front/admin/admin.html',
            controller: 'AdminController'
        });
    });
```

Comment: Use non-`min.js` version when developing, which will give you more clue when things went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject **ui.bootstrap** module dependency in your module initialization not in your controller. Check for dependency injection in controller too.

```
      angular.module('FriendZone',['ui.bootstrap']).controller('AdminController', ['$scope', '$state', '$http',
        function ($scope, $state, $http) {
         $scope.getUsers = function() {

        };

       $scope.getUsers();
}]);
```

Comment: Hi, so I plugged in your code however now nothing renders but there aren't any errors coming up. Do you know what might be wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've added routing code in the post, it's in the app.js file in my setup.

Comment: Have you added default state **.state('STATE_NAME', {url: '/',templateUrl:'index.html',controller: 'YOUR_CONTROLLER'})**

Comment: Okay so I have fixed the injection error and the blank page. However when I try to use uib-tabset and any bootstrap directives. Nothing shows up?

Comment: This is the bit of html that's problematic:  

<uib-tabset active="active">
        <uib-tab index="1" heading="Static title 1 ">Static content 1 </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="2" heading="Static title 2 ">Static content 2 </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="3" heading="Static title 3 ">Static content 3 </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the dependency at the module level, which is usually defined in the app.js file. The controller uses code defined in dependencies, which are injected when you initialize the module in the module definition. Then in a separate file, which you have linked, you call the module definition which pulls all the dependencies you already have defined.